Convert human readable time to epoch inline with jq for time comparison
I am writing a bash script to compare VM creation date to an epoch time gathered in a previous step to see what VMs were recreated before a certain date. These are bosh vms which gives human readable time. Example: Fri Jul 16 17:34:44 UTC 2024
To get a list of vm creation dates, my bosh command looks like this:
bosh is --vitals --json | jq -r '.Tables[].Rows[].vm_created_at'

What I need is something like this:
bosh is --vitals --json | jq -r '.Tables[].Rows[] | select( .vm_created_at(somehow convert to epoch) < $epoch_from_previous_step).instance_name'

I'm not sure if that is doable in that command. Or do I have to pull each one out and convert...tough to wrap my head around it.  There's anywhere from 75 to 450 VMs in the foundations I am running this against, and I need to find the VMs recreated before an already captured epoch time stamp. Thanks!

Please include a (minimal) example of your input json so we can play with a [mre].

Use .vm_created_at | strptime("‌…") | mktime where strptime converts the string into a broken-down array, which is converted by mktime into Unix epoch seconds (see Dates in the manual). Replace … with the format of your input, e.g. %a %b %d %T %Z %Y

The "UTC" specification in the given example does create some complications.
With gojq, you can get away with using %Z:
$ gojq -R 'strptime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")' <<< "Fri Jul 16 17:34:44 UTC 2024"

But this fails using jq.
If all the human-readable strings use UTC in the same way, you could simply
replace %Z with UTC:
strptime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S UTC %Y")

If that's not the case, then one of many possibilities would be to use sub/2 in conjunction
with %Z, e.g.
jq -R 'sub("UTC";"GMT") | strptime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")' <<< "Fri Jul 16 17:34:44 UTC 2024"


You can save this file as bosh.jq and run it using
bosh is --vitals --json | jq -r -f bosh.jq:
# define function
def convert_time($str): $str|strptime("%a %b %d %T UTC %Y")|mktime;

# set variable or (can also be set using --arg)
"Fri Jul 16 17:34:44 UTC 2024" as $epoch

| .Tables[].Rows[] 
| select(convert_time(.vm_created_at) < convert_time($epoch)).instance_name

Command you provided to get list of VM creation dates
$ bosh is --vitals --json | jq -r '.Tables[].Rows[].vm_created_at' 

Fri Jul 15 17:34:44 UTC 2024
Fri Jul 17 17:34:44 UTC 2024

Command to find VMS recreated before an already captured epoch timestamp
$ bosh is --vitals --json | jq -r \
  --arg epoch "Fri Jul 16 17:34:44 UTC 2024" '
    def convert_time($str): $str|strptime("%a %b %d %T UTC %Y")|mktime; 
    .Tables[].Rows[] 
    | select(convert_time(.vm_created_at) < convert_time($epoch)).instance_name
  '

Box 1


I'm assuming the output for bosh is --vitals --json is similar to:
{                                        
  "Tables": [                                                        
    {"Rows": [{ "vm_created_at": "Fri Jul 15 17:34:44 UTC 2024", "instance_name": "Box 1" }]},
    {"Rows": [{ "vm_created_at": "Fri Jul 17 17:34:44 UTC 2024", "instance_name": "Box 2" }]}
  ]        
}

